# Calling a function or script conditionally if variable exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, express

Using ExpressJS I render an EJS view, sometimes when I render the view I pass a variable(myVar). I would like to call a function; on the condition that variable(myVar) was sent.

The Express route in app.js.

```
    app.get('/viewing/login', function(req, res){
           res.render('viewing/login', {
               title: 'my view',
               locals: myVar     <!------The variable being sent(myVar) ----
           });
    });
```

The function in myScript.js

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('<div></div>')
                .attr('id','overlay')
                .css('opacity', '.60')
                .addClass('active')
                .html(myVar)
                .appendTo('body')
                .slideDown('slow',function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){$('#overlay').slideUp('slow')}, 5000);
             })
       });
```

There is also an EJS file called login.ejs

1. App.js sends myVar to login.ejs
2. The function saved in myScript should run if myVar gets sent to login.ejs
3. Where does the the existence of myVar in login.ejs get validated

What is the method for calling a function(or script) if a variable exists in EJS?

What my code is attempting to do is slide down an overlay with a given error when the person does not type in their username and password correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe one way is to simply do a `typeof` check:

```
if (typeof(myVar) === 'undefined') {
    // variable is undefined send alert, etc;
}
```

Comment: If I put that in a script myVar is not getting passed to the script and if I put that in my view it is not being acknowledged, I assume because of something to do with ejs wanting % notation

Comment: my next idea is to call the script everytime but make the script dependent on myVar somehow so that it couldn't run if it was not there. It just seems like a lengthy hack

Comment: @Four_lo I don't understand, when you say `script` you mean `function`? or you mean your whole code? Please be clear.  What I provided is VALIDATION that a variable is `undefined`. This is a conditional check you would add before using `myVar` in your function that returns to your view.

Comment: Oh ok, The res.render function was in a different javascript file than the function I would like to call. Should I A)combine the javascript files B)pass the variable to the view, then to the second javascript file or C) Is there a relatively simple way to pass the variable from one javascript file to another?

Comment: @Four_lo I don't follow your questions now... please revise your initial question to be as clear as possible, you wanted validation of a var, not something else.  Chat in questions is not the way to go on SO.

Comment: I edited my original question. thank you for your help. Apologies for chat in questions.